# How to use an intent to call up another class?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I am having an issue when trying to go from the main screen of my app to display the data that i have collected in my SQLiteDatabase.  Here is my Application manifest...
I have tried switching the Main.java file from LAUNCHER to DEFAULT and the opposite for the database java file to make it open when it is run and i can get it to display that class that way but not using the button that I have in the Main.java file that is for changing to see the data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder.Locationdbview"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the section in my Main.java file that has to do with the Intent where I am trying to call the Location database java file.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bcalculate:
        area();
        break;
    case R.id.bclear:
        clear();
        break;
    case R.id.bloc:

        Intent in = new
   Intent("com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder.Locationdbview");
        startActivity(in);

        break;
```

I think the error is something simple in my manifest or where I try to use the Intent to switch views...If anyone has any ideas please help.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do both activity have an intent filter in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second activity in the manifest to:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder.Locationdbview"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

You don't need any filters there.

Change the call in your firstActivity to:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Locationdbview.class));
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but nothing worked.  The button clicked but did not switch classes.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if it enters the case R.id.bloc statement?

Comment: I have watched the logcat while I click the button and nothing comes up.  I am still really new to programming and thats about as far as my debugging skills go.  Is this what you were meaning?  Watch for an error?

Comment: No, debugging is not just looking at the logcat and hoping you see something. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A) and [this article](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html) should help you.

Comment: Another thing: Where do you add the click handler to the button? Post this code as well.

Comment: So...figured out what the mistake was...I left out the 
    `bloc.setOnClickListener(this);`
Thanks for all your help and thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this in `Main.java`

```
 Class myclass =Class.forName("com.innovativesolutions.gpsareafinder.Locationdbview");
 Intent in=new Intent(Main.this,myclass);  
 startActivity(in);
```

In Manifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name=".Locationdbview" ></activity>
```

Comment: I am still pretty new at android and as far as logcat goes there is nothing that comes up