# getting location updates after switching between classes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-location

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139605/how-to-use-an-intent-to-call-up-another-class) I was trying to gather location data and store it in a db.  Now when I press back on my phone when running the application to go back to the collection screen the location does not resume updating even though I have and onResume() method...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 0, this);

}
```

Does this method just handle if you leave the app then open it back up?  How do I go about making the app continue to request updates after I just hit the back button from when viewing the location data in the database?

Comment: Do you have different Activities for your DB and your location requests?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to android, are you asking how those are called in my application?I have a separate class for my database and to display the database and the database is initialized in its own class.  I just pass the data to the class.  However the location request is initialized in the main part of the app and the onResume() and onPause methods are in that class also.  Let me know if I am completely missing what you are asking lol